# How can I have math expressions in click commands in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I know this works

```
x = 625 + offset
Click %x%, 575
```

But

```
Click %625 + offset%, 575
```

or

```
Click 625 + %offset%, 575
```

doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how I can have math expressions with commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Variables and Expressions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)

> **Force an expression**: An expression can be used in a parameter that does not directly support it (except an OutputVar or InputVar parameter such as those of StringLen) by preceding the expression with a percent sign and a space or tab. This technique is often used to access arrays. For example:

```
FileAppend, % MyArray%i%, My File.txt
MsgBox % "The variable MyVar contains " . MyVar . "."
Loop % Iterations + 1
WinSet, Transparent, % X + 100
Control, Choose, % CurrentSelection - 1
```

So I suggest you try:

```
Click % 625 + %offset%, 575
```

---

If that doesn't work, it might be because the [Click documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) specifically says:

> Since click does not support [expressions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#expressions), variables should be enclosed in percent signs.

If that happens, it might be worth trying [MouseClick](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) instead, as its documentation specifically says:

> The x/y coordinates to which the mouse cursor is moved prior to clicking, which can be expressions.